# Facebook PHP API - Allow users to add events to a Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook API integration that I have almost finshed integrating, but am stuck with one last thing.

The idea of the page is that users can add an event to the page's wall itself. I can get it to add an event to their personal events, and if I loop through my own (/me/accounts) I can get an access token which does post the event to the page's wall.

Does anyone know how you let the users add the events.

PS> I have the manage_pages, create_events, offline_access permissions etc if that's useful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What i think is, in order to add an event for the page, you have to be the Admin for it, thats why it is letting you add events but wont let other users create events.